# After changing AAM SharePoint 2013 Prompting for Credentials

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, central-administration, alternate-access-mapping, iis7

I have SharePoint 2013 foundation.  Till now I am connecting with sharepoint website with server name. Now I added new AAM url to connect different url. But when I am trying to access with new AAM url. it keep asking me credentials

[image]

What I did from my side

---

1. Added site bindinging in IIS for new url.
2. Also changed `DisableLoopbackCheck` [link](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us)
3. Updated host file also

Still it is asking for credentials. What next to change?

Answer (score 2):

Add your new URL to the intranet zone in Internet Explorer will make SSO work property, if that's what missing for you?